# How do I make rsync demon log to stdout (instead of a logfile)?

Tags: rsync

I'm running rsync underneath Supervisor.  I normally start rsync daemon like this:

```
rsync --daemon --config=/home/zs6ftad/deployments/cmot_rsync_daemon/rsyncd.conf --no-detach
```

I'd like to make it so that any log messages get echo'd to standard output instead of being stored in the log-file. Is there an option which will make an rsync server behave this way?

Comment: You can use verbose stats and progress : rsync -v --stats --progress if i understand the post, to set this option to the server use .bashrc add an alias with [-v --stats --progress] if you needed as default.

Comment: You can to rsync -v --stats --progress > myNewlog.log, regards.

Comment: surely this does the opposite of what I want? The code example above will put all of rsync daemon's output into myNewlog.log.

Answer (score 5):

You can get rsyncd to log to stdout by setting the `--log-file` argument to `/dev/stdout`

```
rsync --daemon --no-detach --log-file=/dev/stdout
```

Comment: A note for everyone: `--no-detach` is important here to see the output